# In C, how to shuffle pointers of an array index in a random order

Tags: c, pointers, shuffle

I am trying create a function to shuffle an array of integers using pointers for a school assignment, I am newer to c so I'm not exactly sure how it should be done properly.

Below is the code that I've tried so far, but I get a lot of casting errors, or errors telling me cards[] is not an array.

```
void ShuffleDeck(cards[52]){
    int temp;
    int *firstIndxPtr ;
    firstIndxPtr = cards[0];
    int *randIndxPtr1;
    for (int x = 52; x > 0 ; x--){
        randIndxPtr1 = cards[rand() % x];   
        temp = (int) randIndxPtr1;  
        randIndxPtr1 = firstIndxPtr;
        (int) firstIndxPtr = temp;}
}
```

Comment: `(int) firstIndxPtr = temp` casting doesn't work that way. You don't change the type of the variable that you assign to

Comment: If you declare variables with the proper types, normally that means casting should be unnecessary.

Comment: well, you have declared `cards[52]`.... or not? you need a type identifier to put in front of `cards` parameter to make it an array, something like `int cards[52]`, in the parameter declaration of `ShuffleDeck()`.  This is the reason we ask you to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  As posted it is not clear if this is the error you have or simply some typo you made on copying.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your assignment, you need to understand the pointer, and the value it points to, you should use either of the following value for your pointer.

```
firstIndexPtr = &cards[0];
firstIndexPtr = cards;
```

And you cannot pass the array cards[52] as function argument, it should be something like

```
void ShffuleDeck(int *cards, int number_of_cards)
{
}
```